# VBA - Unwanted Listcount Representation Changes Based On Selection

Tags: vba, ms-access, listbox, ms-access-2003

I'm using Access 2003 to develop an application where a user can dynamically generate a query, and then browse through a listbox with the results of their GUI defined query. I allow the column heads to show which counts as an extra row in the results.

The amount of rows returned is limited by the listbox's physical limit of 65535. I also have a list box showing **Row X Of Y Selected** in a textbox.

The message is generated each time the user clicks in the listbox, the code in the event handler is:

> > Me!txtRowCount.Value = "Row " & (Me!listDynamicSearchResult.ListIndex + 1) & _
> >     " Of " & (Me!listDynamicSearchResult.ListCount - 1) & " Selected"

Usually the code shows **Row X of 65534 Selected**, since I opt out counting the header in the listbox. As the user gets closer to the maximum value, the Y value, 65534, changes to 65535 and stays at that max number until I requery or clear the form.

So, why does the listcount property not show the appropriate value until I am closer to the maximum value?

Comment: Also, the actual listcount value changes from 65535 to 65536.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior might be something similar to what happens in regard to recordsets and counting within recordsets

```
Before we get into the examples, you need to understand how RecordCount works. 
It does not tell you the number of records in a recordset. Rather, it tells you
the count of records accessed in the Recordset. They may or may not be the same
thing.
```

Source: http://www.baldyweb.com/RecordCounts.htm

A workaround might be to use `DCount` but I'm guessing that's potentially expensive to call on 64k lines

Comment: I think your solution would give an accurate result, but an aggregate function on every selection seems like a nightmare.

At the end of the day it is just off by one, I am/was just curious to why it is doing it.

Comment: I haven't found anythin better, so I'm choosing this as the answer.